# ASP.NET Identity: Cannot sign in on OnApplyRedirect

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, owin

I'm trying to overrule OnApplyRedirect, and sign in a user if certain query string parameters are present. I use CookieAuthentication.

I can see that AuthenticationResponseGrant in the AuthenticationManager is set correctly, but the user is not signed in and no cookie is set. I'm using the same code as I use in one of my controllers to sign in the user.

```
var context = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext();
var user = UserRepository.FindUserByQueryString(request.Query);
var userManager = new UserManager<OrganizationUser>(new OrganizationUserStore());
var identity = userManager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);    
context.Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = true }, identity);
context.Response.Redirect(request.Uri);
```

What on earth am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to sign in the user in the OnApplyRedirect callback. Maybe it's too early in the OWIN pipeline, I don't know.

I ended up redirecting to a new controller method that accepts the same query string parameters, and sign in the user from there, then finally redirecting to the original target url.

If anyone can help me avoid this hack I'd be very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something similar - a solution to security testing on localhost for a distributed identity implementation where the application in question is not the login application.   I wanted our team to be able to work with iis express and not have to stand up a full local iis with the login application running to develop other applications.

I tried using middleware and found that it was either too early or too late in the owin pipeline.   I also tried your approach above of canceling the redirect and signing in the user when localhost conditions were met but found that I was getting strange errors.

I don't have an answer but wanted to say your solution helped me somewhat.   I ended up using logic in the OnApplyRedirect to switch between the centralized login application's login, and a localhost sign-in controller action in the local application.

Here's my implementation in case it helps anyone else going down this road:

```
OnApplyRedirect = context =>
{    
    // check for localhost and use the application's little localhost login controller action
    if (
        //no user is signed in
          String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(context.OwinContext.Authentication.User.Identity.Name)
        //and we are on localhost
        && (context.OwinContext.Request.Uri.Host.ToLower() == "localhost")
        && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LocalHost_UserName"])
    )
    {
        if (context.OwinContext.Request.PathBase.ToString().Length > 0)
        {
            //we are on local iis with an application name in the path
            //goto /[Application]/Home/LocalhostSignIn
            context.RedirectUri = context.OwinContext.Request.PathBase.ToString() + LocalHostSignInRelativePath;
        }
        else
        {
            //no path base (pure localhost:port)
            //goto /Home/LocalhostSignIn
            context.RedirectUri = LocalHostSignInRelativePath;
        }
    }
    else //standard scenario, route them to the normal login application
    {
        //switch this applications path with the centralized login app's path (declared above in this helper class)
        context.RedirectUri = context.RedirectUri.Replace(context.OwinContext.Request.PathBase.ToString(), HomeApplicationRelativePath);
    }
    context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
},
```

Controller:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult LocalhostSignIn()
{
    Microsoft.Owin.IOwinContext owinContext = ControllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.GetOwinContext();
    if (
        //no user is signed in
        String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(owinContext.Authentication.User.Identity.Name)
            //and we are on localhost
        && (owinContext.Request.Uri.Host.ToLower() == "localhost")
        && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LocalHost_UserName"])
    )
    {
        IdentityHelper.SignUserIntoContext(owinContext, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LocalHost_UserName"]);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Some error message");
    }
}
```

Sign in Logic:

```
/// <summary>
/// This will sign in a username WITHOUT A PASSWORD!!!!!
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context"></param>
/// <returns>T/F depending on whether or not the UserName passed in was valid</returns>
/// <remarks>
/// Used by WindowsLogin to sign in a domain credential to the Identity (cookie) authentication model
/// Used by LocalhostSignIn to sign in the username located in the LocalHost_UserName for local development (so you don't need a local sign-in application)
/// </remarks>
public static bool SignUserIntoContext(IOwinContext owinContext, string UserName)
{
    var userManager = owinContext.GetUserManager<IntranetUserManager>();
        IntranetUser intranetUser = userManager.FindByName(UserName);

    if (intranetUser != null)
    {
        var signInManager = owinContext.Get<IntranetSignInManager>();
        //sign the user into intranet identity
        signInManager.SignIn(intranetUser, false, false);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Web.Config:

```
<location path="Home/LocalhostSignIn">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
            <allow users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authorization>
                <clear />
                <add accessType="Allow" users="?" />
                <add accessType="Allow" users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

If anyone has any tips or suggestions or feedback they would be appreciated.

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped you tackle your problems. We're still using the described hack successfully. Still not very pretty though.. :)